# Apply a CSS effect to only the first 10 <a> tags of a div

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to apply a CSS effect to the first 10 `<a>` tags of a div?

This is my approach, but I believe there has to be a better solution:

```
a:nth-child(1), a:nth-child(2), a:nth-child(3), a:nth-child(4),
a:nth-child(5), a:nth-child(6), a:nth-child(7), a:nth-child(8),
a:nth-child(9), a:nth-child(10){ color:#4faacb; }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is a range option available. I'm just not sure what kind of browser support there is for it at this time.

Comment: Why not use a JS-loop to apply a class to the first 10 links, then use that class as a selector?

Comment: a:nth-child(-n+11) { color: #4faacb }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this CSS should do the trick

```
a:nth-child(-n+10) { color: #4faacb }
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/z8fMr/2/)

Hope this helps

Comment: @RayZ mark it as accepted (tick next to the number and arrows) so other people can find the solution!

Comment: I will surely... Wait a moment

Comment: @Barney: Considering he has more than a few dozen questions with accepted answers, surely he knows well enough that a reminder isn't necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using an `nth-of-type` formula in combination with `not`:

```
div > a:not(:nth-of-type(1n+11)){
    color: red;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/barney/bJcH5/).

Comment: Either `:nth-of-type()` or `:nth-child()` will work if every child of the `div` is guaranteed to be an `a`.